# How to make email alert to be sent when a openstack instance is down?

Tags: ssh, monitoring, openstack, status

Does openstack have any feature to achieve this scenario:

1. Check the status of openstack instances (user is able to ssh and work or not).
2. Get the set of instances IP which is not working.
3. Send an email to a user with list of not working instances.

If this is not available, any alternatives?.

Went through https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Operations/Tools. but could not find the one which suits my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

For that you can install elasticsearch nodes on your instances, and thanks to plugins like heartbeat (https://www.elastic.co/beats/heartbeat), you can have an overview of the availability of your servers, and their access.

Monitoring is the best practice for having this kind of information, the ELK (Elasticsearch Logstash Kibana) suite does it very well for free and allows you to alert (by email or other) if one of your instances no longer responds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mistral project for such used case , Set a cloud cron for it.

Comment: what do you mean by "Mistral project", please describe